# I want to update a row if Ptnt_id already exists if not add new one

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, xampp

I want to update a row if Ptnt_id already exists if not add new one

```
IF EXISTS (select * from `tbl_medicalhistory` where `Ptnt_id` =0) THEN
    update `tbl_medicalhistory` set `txt_tongue`= 'UPDATED' where `Ptnt_id` = 0;
  ELSE 
    INSERT INTO `tbl_medicalhistory`(`idMed`, `Ptnt_id`, `txt_tongue`, `txt_palate`, `txt_tonsil`, `txt_lips`, `txt_floorOfMouth`, `txt_cheeks`, `txt_allergy`, `txt_HeartDisease`, `txt_BloodDyscracia`, `txt_Diabetes`, `txt_kidney`, `txt_liver`, `txt_hygiene`, `txt_others`) VALUES (20],20,"This","New","Table","","","","","","","","","","","OTHERS");
```

idMed will be the primary key and Ptnt_id will be foreign key so if Ptnt_id already exist it will just update the entire row otherwise it will add another row with a new idMed and Ptnt_id
Can someone please help me to write that QUERY/PROCEDURE?

Comment: Use the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax of MySQL. [Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax.

A simplified version of the query above would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_medicalhistory`(`idMed`, `Ptnt_id`, `txt_tongue`) 
VALUES (20,20,"This")

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `txt_tongue`="That";
```

Given that Ptnt_id is a UNIQUE or PRIMARY index, a row will be inserted of one not exists with Ptnt_id=20, otherwise if the row exists, its txt_tongue column will be updated.

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: idMed will be the primary key and Ptnt_id will be foreign key so if Ptnt_id already exist it will just update the entire row otherwise it will add another row with a new idMed and Ptnt_id

Comment: Then Ptnt_id is not an index? Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE  tbl_medicalhistory`?

Comment: Can't post images cause still new here :(

Comment: You can update the question and paste the textual output in there.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROCEDURE_NAME]`
`(`
`@Ptnt_id int`
`)`
`BEGIN`
`IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tbl_medicalhistory] WHERE Ptnt_id=@Ptnt_id)`
`BEGIN`
`UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_medicalhistory]`
`SET txt_tongue= 'UPDATED'`
`WHERE Ptnt_id=@Ptnt_id`
`END`
`ELSE`
`BEGIN`
`INSERT INTO [dbo].tbl_medicalhistory(idMed, Ptnt_id, txt_tongue, txt_palate, txt_tonsil, txt_lips, txt_floorOfMouth, txt_cheeks, txt_allergy, txt_HeartDisease, txt_BloodDyscracia, txt_Diabetes, txt_kidney, txt_liver, txt_hygiene, txt_others) VALUES (20,@Ptnt_id,"This","New","Table","","","","","","","","","","","OTHERS")`
`END`
`END`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write c# coding this may help you

```
patient_id="123"; 
string str1="";  
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(constr);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("SELECT ptnt_id FROM TABLE  ", con);
SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
string pid=dr[0].toString();
  if(patient_id == pid)
   {
     str1="true";
   }

}

if(str1 == true)
{
con.close();
con.open();
SqlCommand cmd1=new SqlCommand("UPDATE TABLE SET ..... WHERE ptnt_id='"+pid+"' ",con);
cmd.executeNonQuery();
}
else
{
con.close();
con.open();
SqlCommand cmd1=new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES .... ",con);
cmd.executeNonQuery();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable datatype depends on your requirement

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROCEDURE_NAME] (
    @Ptnt_id INT
    ,@idMed INT
    ,@Ptnt_id INT
    ,@txt_tongue NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@txt_palate NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@txt_tonsil NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@txt_lips NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@txt_floorOfMouth NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@txt_cheeks NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@txt_allergy NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@txt_HeartDisease NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@txt_BloodDyscracia NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@txt_Diabetes NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@txt_kidney NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@txt_liver NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@txt_hygiene NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@txt_others NVARCHAR(50)
    )

BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM [dbo].[tbl_medicalhistory]
            WHERE Ptnt_id = @Ptnt_id
            )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_medicalhistory]
        SET txt_tongue = 'UPDATED'
        WHERE Ptnt_id = @Ptnt_id
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].tbl_medicalhistory (
            idMed
            ,Ptnt_id
            ,txt_tongue
            ,txt_palate
            ,txt_tonsil
            ,txt_lips
            ,txt_floorOfMouth
            ,txt_cheeks
            ,txt_allergy
            ,txt_HeartDisease
            ,txt_BloodDyscracia
            ,txt_Diabetes
            ,txt_kidney
            ,txt_liver
            ,txt_hygiene
            ,txt_others
            )
        VALUES (
            20
            ,@Ptnt_id
            ,@idMed
            ,@Ptnt_id
            ,@txt_tongue
            ,@txt_palate
            ,@txt_tonsil
            ,@txt_lips
            ,@txt_floorOfMouth
            ,@txt_cheeks
            ,@txt_allergy
            ,@txt_HeartDisease
            ,@txt_BloodDyscracia
            ,@txt_Diabetes
            ,@txt_kidney
            ,@txt_liver
            ,@txt_hygiene
            ,@txt_others
            )
    END
END
```